# Stuck on 404 error while trying to test Express route. Possible Express routing or MongoDB Atlas connection issue?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mern

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. My server runs fine and doesn't log any errors in the console, but I still can't hit the route I'm testing (404 err). There are no issues present with the way in which I'm attempting to hit the route. I have built out a lot of seemingly-needless express routing because my API will eventually be large enough to warrant it, so maybe the problem is there? Or perhaps there's an issue with my db configuration. Potentially relevant code below...

conn.mjs:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

mongoose.connect(
  process.env.ATLAS_URI,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);

export default mongoose.connection;
```

server.mjs:

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
// dotenv config
import "./loadEnvironment.mjs";
import path from "path";
import db from './db/conn.mjs'

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build")));
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "../client/build/index.html"));
});

db.once('open', () => {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port: ${PORT}`);
  });
})
```

routes/index.js:

```
import { Router } from "express";

import apiRoutes from "./api/index";

Router.use("/api", apiRoutes);

export default Router;
```

routes/api/index.js:

```
import { Router } from "express";
import stylistRoutes from "./stylistRoutes";

Router.use("/stylists", stylistRoutes);

export default Router;
```

routes/api/stylistRoutes.js:

```
import express from "express";
import Stylist from "../../models/Stylist";

const router = express.Router;

// create new stylist
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, title, bio, image_url, email, password, adminKey } = req.body;
    const stylist = new Stylist({
      name,
      title,
      bio,
      image_url,
      email,
      password,
      adminKey,
    });
    await stylist.save();
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "New stylist created!",
      stylist,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({
      message: err.message,
    });
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: const router = express.Router or const router = express.Router() ?